# How do I transfer files from SD card to windows PC. No network or memory stick!

Tags: sd-card, data-transfer

I realise this may be impossible, but...

I am using an Raspi for a project at work. I would like to transfer files from the PC to the pi, something that I know there are plenty of ways to do.

However, all of these methods use either a USB pen drive, or a LAN connection. Currently I am not permitted to connect it to the LAN network at work, and memory sticks need to be encrypted in a way that can only be decrypted on windows machines. For some reason the SD card adaptor does not need encrypting. If there any way I can transfer the files to the OS SD card for the pi?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the SD card adaptor does not need encrypting"?  Does that mean that on your corporate PC you have an SD card slot in which you can put an SD card to which you can write unencrypted data?

Comment: Apologies. SD cards plugged into the USB-SD card adaptor on the work PC do not need encrypting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can write unencrypted data to an SD card you can use an SD card USB adapter to connect the unencrypted SD card to your Raspberry Pi.

Below is a picture of one such card.  [Here is a link](http://blog.treonauts.com/2007/09/treo-memory-car.html) to a web page that describes this adapter in more detail.

[image]

Once you connect this USB adapter to your Pi with the SD card inserted you should be able to access the information on the SD card as a FAT file system on the Raspberry Pi.

You can also just connect your Raspberry Pi OS SD card to your work PC, however, without modifying the standard Pi OS SD card layout you will only be able to write files to the `/boot` FAT file system.  You can also repartition the SD card and create a second larger FAT partition and file system for large file transfers.

However, by using a second SD card and USB adapter you should be able to move the SD card between the Pi and your PC without having to power off or reboot your Pi.  That being said you would need to unmount the SD card from the Pi before removing the SD card from the Pi.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I need to aquire another SD card. I might look into repartitioning the OS SD card for future though.

Comment: You can mount EXT4 on Windows you know :) http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/  I think its read only but some support write.